# How do I pretend duplicate values in my read database with CQRS

Tags: cqrs

Say that I have a User table in my ReadDatabase (use SQL Server). In a regulare read/write database I can put like a index on the table to make sure that 2 users aren't addedd to the table with the same emailadress.

So if I try to add a user with a emailadress that already exist in my table for a diffrent user, the sql server will throw an exception back.

In Cqrs I can't do that since if I decouple the write to my readdatabas from the domain model, by puting it on an asyncronus queue I wont get the exception thrown back to me, and I will return "OK" to the UI and the user will think that he is added to the database, when infact he will never be added to the read database.

I can do a search in the read database checking if there is a user already in my database with the emailadress, and if there is one, then thru an exception back to the UI. But if they press the save button the same time, I will do 2 checks to the database and see that there isn't any user in the database with the emailadress, I send back that it's okay. Put it on my queue and later it will fail (by hitting the unique identifier).

Am I suppose to load all users from my EventSource (it's a SQL Server) and then do the check on that collection, to see if I have a User that already has this emailadress. That sounds a bit crazy too me...

How have you people solved it?

The way I can see is to not using an asyncronized queue, but use a syncronized one but that will affect perfomance really bad, specially when you have many "read storages" to write to...

Need some help here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching  for CQRS Set Based Validation will give you solutions to  this issue.

Greg Young posted about the business impact of embracing eventual consistency http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/08/12/eventual-consistency-and-set-validation/

Jérémie Chassaing posted about discovering missing aggregate roots in the domain http://thinkbeforecoding.com/post/2009/10/28/Uniqueness-validation-in-CQRS-Architecture

Related stack overflow questions:

[How to handle set based consistency validation in CQRS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916899/how-to-handle-set-based-consistency-validation-in-cqrs)
[CQRS Validation & uniqueness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140592/cqrs-validation-uniqueness)

Comment: Not the answer I wanted but it makes sense. I did get an idea that I could peek me queue to see if there was information there about a user created/edited with the same email-adress.